# Handle redirects on proxied server

Tags: nginx

Hi I'm trying to make mirror for website.ru at website.com

It should display website.com in browser and proxy_pass all traffic to website.ru.

Here is my config:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name www.website.com website.com website.com;
        ssl                 on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/star.website.com_20141128.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/star.website.com.key;
        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 100m;
        charset  utf-8;



        location / {
                client_max_body_size 5m;
                add_header      Access-Control-Allow-Headers Nt-Jqp,X-Requested-With;
                add_header      Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;


                proxy_busy_buffers_size 1024k;
                proxy_buffer_size 64k;
                proxy_buffers 32 64k;

                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host             tradernet.ru;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_pass https://-IP-OF-WEBSITE.RU:443;

        }

}
```

Problem is that when `website.ru` make 301 redirect, user also redirected to `website.ru`. I want to stay'em on `website.com` and just redisplay url where he was redirected.

Say, `website.ru` redirects user to `website.ru/login` and user is redirected from `website.com` to `website.ru/login`, but I want to show user `website.com/login`, instead of redirecting to `website.ru/login`

How's that should work? Pls help

Comment: `I want to stay'em on website.com` - what does this mean? Generally the question isn't clear.

Comment: Do you control `website.ru`? Otherwise it doesn't look like appropriate usage.

Comment: BTW, do you realize what `proxy_redirect` is for?

Comment: @AD7six, it's just an english language domain for website.ru. I don't want english users to use webiste.ru and don't want to make whole new server for english users.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, I do control website.ru

Comment: @AlexeyTen, no I don't really understand what `proxy_redirect` stands for - just copied it from some tutorial

Comment: Then why you do it hard way? Just DNS CNAME and one more `server_name` in `website.ru` and you've got it.